# Is there a way to get a unique web device id for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to implement a unique login condition in a Firebase web project and I'd like to grab a unique device id, along with the logged in userId to test a condition for multiple devices logged into the same account.

I already have the solution working where I don't let a user login if another device is already logged in using the same account. The reason I want a unique device id, is that I want to auto logout the other device, not the newest one to log in.

Note, this is for a PWA not Android/iOS mobile app.

Comment: Hi, stuck into a similar problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, never found anything that worked. I think you pretty much need to do something serverside to grab an IP address or something like that

Comment: Did you consider using this npm package [device-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/device-uuid)?

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that one in mind. My design requirements have changed so I no longer need a UID.